# Blue spots in compositing after color mix

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, blender-internal-render-engine

I use different pass for specular in BI, make Glare for specular and try to combine it with original picture with Mix node. When I use screen or overlay mix i get final picture with ugly blue spots instead white. What I'm doing wrong and what kind of Mix should i use to combine specular with original image?

[image]

Comment: Please show your render and composite nodes, and if possible provide the blend. Hard to answer a question without any sort of context.

Comment: IDK what's point, but I got this bug after I'd turned back to BI after Cycles

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the *Add* mixing mode when you want to add more white pixels to the image, then plug the specular image in the top (so it adds to the bottom image).

Example:

[image]